Migratiom from paperclip to carrierwave - uploading attachment to amazon S3
my rails application attachments were on paperclip after migration to carrierwave i want to keep old attachments uploaded to amazon S3 so i tried attachments urls be in this format:
"https://static.tagmond.com/static.tagmond.com/stores/banners/000/000/032/original/cover_large_app_2.jpg"
so i added below method to carrierwave uploader
    def paperclip_path
     'stores/banners/:id_partition/:style/:basename.:extension'
    end

but i got issue on carrierwave initializer config file
here is my config file in carrierwave.rb:
{
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.storage = :fog
  config.fog_provider = 'fog/aws'
  config.fog_credentials = {
    provider: 'AWS',
    aws_access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    aws_secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
    region: ENV['AWS_REGION'],  //"eu-north-1"


    
    # host: ENV['S3_HOST_NAME'], //"aws.tagmond.com"
    # endpoint: "https://static.tagmond.com"
  }
  config.fog_directory  = ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'] //"static.tagmond.com"

}
I dont exactly know which combination of these three host, endpoint & fog_directory gives me the answer.
despite url format i have problem with uploading to S3 it keeps giving me this error:
[fog][WARNING] fog: the specified s3 bucket name(static.tagmond.com) contains a '.' so is not accessible over https as a virtual hosted bucket, which will negatively impact performance.  For details see: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html
I tried raising issue in carrierwave and fog at github

You mention an error from carrierwave initializer, could you provide a bit more detail on what error you are seeing there?
The warning about bucket names shouldn't directly cause any issues. As it suggests it will negatively impact performance, but things should still work.

Well this line is invalid config.fog_directory  = ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'] //"static.tagmond.com" so maybe that's the error? Seems like you are trying to make a comment but using the wrong syntax for ruby i.e. // is a comment in languages like Javascript, Java, C++, PHP, etc. but in Ruby we use #
